# Swift 5 - how to create a tab bar with a centre circle button? | noob here

Tags: swift, xcode11

New to Swift and Stack Overflow! Found similar post(s), though the answers were still not enough guidance for me to figure it out. So would really appreciate if a bit more detailed guidance can be provided.

I would like to create a tab bar with 5 tab items, with the middle tab item essentially a centre round add button similar to this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwTyq.png)

I have seen a post that seems to suggest that I don't need to use an actual button element, as I can just change the icon to white when the icon is selected, and create a circle in the background of the middle tab item...Except I'm so new to this that I cannot figure out how to do either. I've only managed to customise tab colors when the item is active or inactive.

Can anyone help please?

Sorry it's a basic question. Much appreciated for your input.

Comment: did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

if you have whatever image you want to be your tab bar image in your assets, you can do this in the storyboard. You need to add a tab bar controller, and connect whatever views you want to be for each tab by holding down control from tab bar controller and choosing a view controller/nav controller and choosing the relationship segue (view controllers).

[image]

then clicking on that view controller you just made a tab, there should be a tab at the bottom. click on the tab image and in the right panel you can edit title and image. choose your image and you should be all set.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your input. Sorry I wasn't clear. What I'm struggling with isn't connecting views with the tab bar controller, but rather - how do I create the 'add' button in the centre, especially since the circle is a different size from all the other tab icons? Just for curiosity, what if I also want to create drop shadow on this 'add' button? Thanks!

Comment: what happens if you set the blue plus button from your example as the tab image? that isnt what you are looking for?